# what is the best way to acquire hops for exporting

Tags: commercial

Here recently me and my have been discussing going into selling hops over seas where there is a demand for them. That being said would it be better to buy land and grow,or buy from local farmers? we have a hops commissioner here in which im going into this coming week i just came across this forum, so i thought i would ask...... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have millions of dollars, you don't want to buy land and grow hops.  It's simply not as easy as just "growing hops".  You also have to have processing facilities.  You should contact a major wholesaler like Hopunion or S.S. Steiner.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Denny's points, you could see if your own region has something similar to the [Northeast Hop Alliance](http://www.northeasthopalliance.org/) or whether any nearby agricultural colleges have programs like UVM's [Vermont Hops Project](http://www.uvm.edu/extension/cropsoil/hops) (to use examples local to me). You may be able to find a good deal of up-to-date research and information on breeding, growing, processing, marketing and selling hops.

Answer (score 1):

Also bear in mind that exporting means that you have to adhere to the rules and regulations of the country that you are exporting to. This means providing certificates to ensure that the product meets their safety requirements. For instance: America has a type of mite that can kill all of South Africa's hops, so if you want to being hops from USA into SA, you have to provide them with proper documentation that the hops does not carry that mite.

To add a bit to Denny's points: If you plant hops, your first year will have very low yield, so expect at least one year of low/no income.

Have you been to a hop farm? There is a surprising amount of construction required for the hops to GROW! Trellises and irrigation is critical. And then there is harvesting, cleaning, processing, packaging, storing!

Just be aware of the whole process. There might be some unexpected, very expensive lessons if you do not do all your research.

Good luck with your venture.